# How can I restart the VI core on Noveria?

Tags: mass-effect

On my previous playthroughs I have essentially 'skipped' this puzzle by using 100 omni-gel; on this playthrough however I do not have 100 omni-gel so I need to solve the puzzle.

[image]

The on screen prompt simply states that I need to manually reconfigure the data banks and must transfer the module stack from Core 1 to Core 2 or 3. It appears that I can only move a single part of each stack at once, and that precedence is given to modules higher up the stack.

How can I transfer the module stack from Core 1 to one of the other cores, in order to restart the VI on Noveria?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The puzzle you face to manually restart the VI core is a particular one called the [Towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi).

Follow the solution under "iterative solution".  The basic is to take the top block from Stack 1, move it to, let's say, Stack 2.  Then take the next, and move it to Stack 3.  Then move the top of Stack 2 to Stack 3, and remove another from Stack 1.

Or your can look at the animation on the wikipedia page, which provides a clearer explanation:

> [image]
>
> <sub>by [aka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Aka) on [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tower_of_Hanoi_4.gif)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

From your description, this is equivalent to the [Towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) puzzle. The complete sequence of moves is as follows:

1. Move from 1 to 2
2. Move from 1 to 3
3. Move from 2 to 3
4. Move from 1 to 2
5. Move from 3 to 1
6. Move from 3 to 2
7. Move from 1 to 2
8. Move from 1 to 3
9. Move from 2 to 3
10. Move from 2 to 1
11. Move from 3 to 1
12. Move from 2 to 3
13. Move from 1 to 2
14. Move from 1 to 3
15. Move from 2 to 3